# How to build appx and xap packages in the winjs universal project?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app

I didn't find how to build appx and xap packages in the winjs universal project. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universal apps are appx, not xap (Silverlight).

In order to create one you need to go to the Solution Explorer in VS, right click on your project and hit Store -> Create App Package

[image]